# Generic, Inclusive Term for HMI (Human Machine Interface) Feedback to User

Tags: nouns

I'm looking for a noun in a military setting whose meaning would capture all the feedback a user gets from a digital dashboard/controller (the HMI mentioned in the title).

For example, much like the interface of a smartphone or a dashboard on a vehicle, the user can use the HMI to send commands, check the status of things (like a speedometer or tachometer), and more.  Some feedback the user gets is like a text message.  No intervention is required.  It's simply information.  Other feedback is like the "Windows Update" notifications on a computer that ask "Would you like to update now?"  It requires a decision and an action before the notification goes away.

I'm looking for a term that would describe both the passive notifications and the "active" notifications (for lack of a better term).  I've thought of "readout," "instrument," and "feedback."  However, none of them seem to quite capture the spirit I'm looking for.

Note - I apologize if I've tagged the question incorrectly.  This StackExchange has some pretty cool, complex rules for what gets sorted where, and I did my best!

Comment: Each service (and for each nation) will have its own jargon that may not make sense to people not "in the know", and in some cases might even seem contradictory. You are probably best advised to ask someone from within the military establishment you are interested in.

Comment: Feedback seems good.

Comment: Presentation Information.  Feedback should be reserved for information returned as a result of an input action.